# Do vector elements need to be movable?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I noticed that requirements of std::vector on its elememt type T changed from C++03 to C++0x. T now does not need to be copy constructible anymore, but move constructibility suffices.

Is it required for T even if we don't potentially reallocate?

```
vector<boost::scoped_ptr<int>> x(numberElements);
```

I don't see a need for a move here. What does the specification say?

Comment: Well, it's required by the standard... even though your actual implementation may work just fine with immobile objects.

Comment: @kerrek it seems to me that this is a major feature loss compared to `new` arrays. whats the reason for the requirement?

Comment: You can always have a `std::unique_ptr<T[]> p(new T[N])` for "once only" allocations. The requirement is just part of the standard container requirements... I don't know *why* it doesn't contain a whole lot of special exceptions, other than to keep the concept simple. For example, you can use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` for the exact same generated code in C++11 as your own solution, so it's really not a short-coming in any sense.

Comment: i expect to meet a whole lot of c++03 classes that are not movable in my future c++11 life.

Comment: sad to hear that std::array apparently requires movability too. {foo}-style initialization doesn't necessarily require movability, so we here have a big feature loss compared to simple c automatic arrays too.

Comment: But that's true for *any* array, even automatic C-arrays: Your type needs to be copy-initializable for aggregate initialization.

Comment: @kerrek, no that is not correct.

Comment: Oh, isn't it? I thought I had read through that section once, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Non-movable classes are OK as long as they are copy-constructible. That is, anything which used to work with C++ 2003 (with respect to the containers) should still work. However, additional types can now also be used with the containers.

Comment: @dietmar if a type is copy constructible, i was in the impression that it is also move constructible. after all, copying from an rvalue is still copying, and being an exact copy of another object is a subset of allowable states of "unspecified state". but to clarify independent of whether my memory serves me right: I meant classes that can neither be copied, nor be "resource-stealing moved".

Comment: If you use copy-initialization (such as in `Type foo[4] = {...}`), the `Type` still needs to be copy-constructible, even if the actual copying operation is elided. You can default initialize arrays of non-trivial types, but copy-initializing them requires being able to copy them. So there's not much difference between `Type[n]` and `array<T, n>`.

Comment: @nicol since you left out the part that in your comment reads "..." i have no idea what it is that you are actually saying.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: My point is that it doesn't matter what goes in the `...`; it still requires that `Type` be copy-constructible.

Comment: @nicol, that is incorrect. list initialization doesnt do the copy dance, even if you end up with calling constructors.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Any spec quotes or sections to corroborate that?

Comment: @nicol i cannot, because this is the effect of an absent requirement. you will need to crawl the whole standard in order to find that I'm right.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: `std::array` is an aggregate, just like `Type[]`. Therefore, it uses the same aggregate initialization rules that `Type[]` does. Thus, if `Type[]` doesn't do "the copy dance", neither does `std::array`. So what operations are you using on this `array` that require moving?

Comment: @nicol i cannot tell you. kerrek said that it would require movability and i trusted him. apparently what i understood him to say is not correct, because both howard and dietmar say that types are not required to be move constructible out of thin air.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: But he didn't say anything about `std::array`; his comment was about `std::vector`. So I don't see where you went from his comment to "*sad to hear that std::array apparently requires movability too. {foo}-style initialization doesn't necessarily require movability, so we here have a big feature loss compared to simple c automatic arrays too.*" Unless that was a typo and you meant `std::vector`.

Comment: @nicol i was in the impression that std::array is a container template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to 23.3.6.2 [vector.cons] paragraph 4 the constructor you are using requires `DefaultInsertable`. Since the constructor isn't one of the constructors for the requirements table also asking for `CopyInsertable` there shouldn't be any additional requirements. According to 23.2.1 [container.requirements.general] paragraph 13, `DefaultInsertable` means that the following expression is well-formed:

```
allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p);
```

It seems, this means that the answer depends on the used allocator `A`. I don't quite fancy to analyze the deeper meaning of 20.6.7.2 [allocator.uses.construction]. Let's do the instructor escape: Determining what this paragraph means is left as an exercise!

Comment: +1 *Only* `DefaultInsertable` is required of `T` for this constructor.  `T` need not be `MoveConstructible` nor `CopyConstructible`.  When the default allocator is used, `DefaultInsertable` implies `DefaultConstructible`.  Johannes' code is conforming (assuming `boost::scoped_ptr<int>` is in scope and means what we all think it means).

Comment: @howard ah, thanks for the explanation. now I can sleep without worrying about my code.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb:  I said it was conforming not portable. ;-)  I'm not sure how many implementations are correct on this at this point in time.  I know libc++ is.  I'd be interested in hearing what other implementations work with your example.

Comment: Yes, the behavior changed from C++ 2003 to C++ 2011: In C++ 2003 it was using one default construction followed by `n` copy constructions. Of course, in C++ 2003 the requirements on the types were a lot more demanding: For a type to go into a container it had to be `CopyConstructible`.

Comment: @howard the libstdc++ of gcc4.7.0 compiles my code (tested with a class that just has a default ctor and a deleted copy and move ctor).